# Access the Model in the PartialView from RenderAction

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model, orchardcms, renderaction

Is it possible to access the model in the PartialView returned by RenderAction from the parent view?
I have a controller action that returns a view with a list of items that have geographical data.  I'd like to use the lat/lon to place the items on a map as well, but I don't want to have to parse the html for the data.

Comment: How are you getting these geographical data? Why not put them on a service method then call it from your parent action method?

Comment: @WannaCSharp The short answer is separation of concerns.  I know there are many ways to get the data.  I am trying to keep the controllers and models separate where the data come from different sources and have different purposes.  I was kinda hoping for a solution that just lets me composite data in the view (maybe with Javascript?) rather than counting on the controllers to mix data from multiple sources.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: `RenderAction()` was designed to be it's own *pipeline*, independent and unaware if the call was a real call or a ChildAction.  Since all actions only render, I'd question your design.  Otherwise you have a view the has a dependency on a RenderAction which is not good practice.  Since you want data from your Action, I would rather see you pull all the data, and call a partial view instead.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Thanks for your explanation of why that would be bad practice.  I will do as you suggest.  I guess I really didn't understand `RenderAction()`.